# how to save datepicker value to sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a problem about datepicker feature.

How to save the value of datepicker to sqlite database?

Assume I create a button to set the date and a button to save to database...

main.java

```
public class main extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Calendar dateTime=Calendar.getInstance();
      private SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.addshoppinglist);

        mSaveBttn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBttn);
        mSetDateBttn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.shoppingDate);
        mCancelBttn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancelBttn);
        mSaveBttn.setOnClickListener(this);

        mSetDateBttn.setOnClickListener(this);
        mCancelBttn.setOnClickListener(this);
        helper = new ProductDatabaseHelper(this);
        model = helper.getAll();
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.saveBttn:


            break;

        case R.id.cancelBttn:
            Intent mainIntent = (new Intent(AddShoppingList.this, main.class));
            startActivity(mainIntent);

            break;

        case R.id.shoppingDate:
            showDialog(DIALOG_DATE);

        }
    }
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id){
        switch(id){
        case DIALOG_DATE:
            return new DatePickerDialog(this,new OnDateSetListener(){


                public  void onDateSet(DatePicker view,int year,int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth){
                    dateTime.set(year,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);

                    mSetDateBttn.setText(dateFormatter
                            .format(dateTime.getTime()));

                }
            } ,dateTime.get(Calendar.YEAR),
              dateTime.get(Calendar.MONTH),
              dateTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));



        }

}
```

Does anyone know how to save the date format to database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achive this in the following manner.

```
public  void onDateSet(DatePicker view,int year,int monthOfYear,int dayOfMonth){
                dateTime.set(year,monthOfYear,dayOfMonth);

           int year = year;   // Here you can get day,month and year.
       int month = monthOfYear;
       int day = dayOfMonth;

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues()

    values.put("Day",dayOfMonth);
    values.put("Month",monthOfYear);
    values.put("Year",year);

    }
```

Now use your database helper class to insert values in it.For using database read [this post](http://mfarhan133.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/database-crud-tutorial-for-android/).

Answer (score 4):

```
DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
int month = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
int year = datePicker.getYear();
```

save these as different Columns as day column, month column and year column

OR
 To make a Date object from a DatePicker use this code

```
new Date(datePicker.getYear() - 1900, datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
```

for time use these methods

getCurrentHour()
getCurrentMinute()

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out one **simple way** as i could not find answer searching.    just do as like did in the implemented function **onDateSet** and self-define a function **insertDate**

```
@Override
public void onDateSet (DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {



    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year , month ,dayOfMonth);
    DateFormat Dateformat = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.MEDIUM);
    String date = Dateformat.format(cal.getTime());

 TextView dateText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateVAl);
    dateText.setText("JUST ADDED DATE "+ date);

    godUri = insertDate(year, month, dayOfMonth);
}

private Uri insertDate(  int year , int month , int dayOfMonth   )
{
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(dateContract.DateEntry.COLUMN_YEAR , year  );
    values.put(dateContract.DateEntry.COLUMN_MONTH , month);
    values.put(dateContract.DateEntry.COLUMN_DAY , d`enter code here`ayOfMonth);

    //getContentResolver().insert(  dateContract.DateEntry.CONTENT_URI , values );

     dateDbHelper myDbHelper  = new dateDbHelper(getApplicationContext());
    SQLiteDatabase database = myDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    long rowId = database.insert(dateContract.DateEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    return ContentUris.withAppendedId(dateContract.DateEntry.CONTENT_URI , rowId);

}
```

That object godUri(No Pun Intended) is declared a global variable.
I created the Uri object godUri to store the Uri of the Date just saved by DatePicker.It can come handy like , sending that Uri through intent to another activity.

If you want to see the full code of how I created this whole datePicker activity...go to this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KZoijdM4DsY).
Everything else i mentioned above is modification by me.